How to reference an ItemStack Block in Bukkit Events?
I am currently making a plugin for Minecraft 1.20.6, and I'm trying to setup where when you right click a certain block (AKA My Chest ItemStack but placed) it pops up with my Custom Inventory. But I'm running into an issue where I cannot figure out how to make it so when you click on my Chest ItemStack and that only (without right clicking actual chests)
@EventHandler
public static void onChestClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) { 
  Player player = e.getPlayer();
  Block block e.getClickedBlock();
  if (block != null) {
    if (/* what goes here? */) {
      player.sendMessage( "Shop Chest Clicked");
    }
  }
}

How can I do it?

Firstly, instead of making block != null, you can use e.hasBlock().
Also, if it's blocks previously placed, you can save the location into a config file then check if the clicked location is in this file.
Here is code to check in config:
// this method convert location to string
public static String stringifyLocation(Location loc) {
    return loc.getWorld().getName() + "_" + loc.getBlockX() + "_" + loc.getBlockY() + "_" + loc.getBlockZ();
}

// this method check if the chest is one of us
public boolean isMyChest(Location loc) {
    return plugin.getConfig().getStringList("shop.blocks_chest").contains(stringifyLocation(
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
    // here make all checks about your chest
    if(e.getItemInHand().isSimilar(createChest())) {
        List<String> list = plugin.getConfig().getStringList("shop.blocks_chest"); // list of your chests
        list.add(stringifyLocation(e.getBlock().getLocation()));
        plugin.getConfig().set("shop.blocks_chest", list); // change the value
        plugin.saveConfig(); // save in the config.yml
    }
}

Don't forget to convert this code for you according to your own method already implemented.
